# Cannot find webresource 404

Tags: c#, .net, webresource.axd, webresource

I'm looking for some help into why this web resource can't be found.

I have a third party solution. The demo has a class library project and a few demo pages. I downloaded it ran it, tested it on my local machine. It works!

In order to put it into my own website solution, I've taken the following steps.

1. Created a new class project/solution
2. Copies the class library
   objects .cs and 1 .js from the third party solution into my new
   class project.
3. Added my new project into my web solution

However I'm getting errors which turn out to be 404 not found reported by firebug.

The project only has a couple of references to the webresources so struggling as to how to make it work

using System.Web.UI;

//  embedded javascript resource
[assembly: WebResource( RuleValidation.Controls.RuleValidation.ScriptResName, "text/javascript" )]

```
namespace RuleValidation.Controls
{

public static class RuleValidation
{
    public const string ScriptResName = "RuleValidation.Controls.RuleValidation.js";
    public const string ScriptName = "ruleValidation";

    public const string RenderEvaluationFunction = "evaluationfunction";
    public const string RenderValidationType = "validationtype";
    public const string RenderOperations = "operations";
    public const string RenderSources = "sources";
    public const string RenderScopes = "scopes";
    public const string RenderCompareValues = "comparevalues";
    public const string RenderCompareCounts = "comparecounts";

} 

}
```

Where RuleValidation.Controls is the namespace of the embedded project files.

```
    protected override void OnPreRender( EventArgs e )
    {
        base.OnPreRender( e );
        if ( RenderUplevel )
        {
            Type type = GetType();
            if ( !Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered( type, RuleValidation.ScriptResName ) )
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptResource( type, RuleValidation.ScriptResName );
            }
        }
    }
```

Help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

There is a property on the .js which needed setting to embedresource.